# How can I get INFURAnet ether?

Tags: testnets, faucets

Infura has a testnet: https://explorer.infuranet.io/.  I don't see anything in the docs about getting testnet ether on their testnet.

Does anyone know how to?

Comment: I have the same question. I am trying to get ether into my infuranet account, just like any other test networks kovan, rinkeby, ropsten would do. In other words is there a faucet to InfuraNet Test Network.
https://infuranet.infura.io

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a local geth node in testnet mode and start mining.  Send the mined testnet eth to whatever wallet is associated with your infruanet account.

Another option is go to the gitter chat page for go-ethereum https://gitter.im/ethereum/go-ethereum.  Just ask someone in there nicely to send you some testnet ether to your address.

Comment: The question is specifically about a particular testnet, Infuranet, not any testnet.

Comment: same approach should work,  find the dev chat and ask someone in there who uses that testnet to send you some eth